# Wordpress theme crashes after editing one of its files

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress website with a custom theme running on a Digitalocean LEMP stack setup.

I'm trying to edit one of the theme's `shortcodes` but I get a http 500 error.

I get that error even if I don't change anything, just download the `shortcode` php file, and re-uploading it causing the issue.

I looked at `nginx` log file and I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare some_function() (previously declared in my_shortcode_file.php)
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Reinstate the file from the theme package

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

It's seems your have declare same function two times.

solution check before declaring function
search that function and put that function in if block

```
if(function_exists('some_function')){ 
   // my_function is defined 
   function some_function(){
      // body of fun
  }
}
```